# Saving file to disk receiving fopen error

Tags: uploads, permissions

I have a requirement to save a json file to disk.

I've got as far a the below php.  However i get the following error.

**fopen(/wp-content/content/uploads/artworks.js): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in**

This file is in the correct location. So i assume there is a permission error. I only have ftp access to this server. Obviously wordpress has permission to write to disk. So how can i leverage this permission to save the file

```
$feed_url = 'http://example.com';
$remote_data = file_get_contents($feed_url);
$data = json_decode($remote_data, true);

$works = array();
foreach ($data ['rows'] as $inx => $remote_item_data) {
$works[] = $remote_item_data;
}


$fp = fopen('/wp-content/content/uploads/artworks.js', 'w+');
fwrite($fp, json_encode($works));
fclose($fp);
```

Answer (score -2):

try change to this one

```
$upload_dir = wp_upload_dir();
$fp = fopen( $upload_dir["basedir"] . '/artworks.js', 'w+');
```

Comment: Please, add a littel explanation of what the code does and how it can answer the question.